# Rails Seedbank gem uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using seedbank gem and getting uninitialized constant on the first line of my seed file
User.create(...)

I can run rake db:seed fine without seedbank.

I am using mongoid.

With seedbank I get.

Error is:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant User
/home/user/my_project/db/seeds.rb:4:in `block in define_seed_task'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myi/gems/seedbank-0.3.0/lib/seedbank/dsl.rb:24:in `module_eval'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myi/gems/seedbank-0.3.0/lib/seedbank/dsl.rb:24:in `block in define_seed_task'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myi/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myi/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed => db:seed:common => db:seed:original
```

Comment: Is the `User` model defined within your application?

Comment: yes it is. rake db:seed works fine if I don't have gem 'seedbank' in gemfile

Answer (score 0):

An uninitialized constant could be caused because your database isn't set up with a User model.

https://github.com/james2m/seedbank shows how to reset and setup the database with seedbank:

```
rake db:reset
```

This will also seed the database so if the command runs successfully, you are in the clear! The reset command is extended by seedbank but also exists in ActiveRecord by default.

**CAUTION: Running the db:reset command will delete all database content so use it with care.**

Comment: I am using mongodb, so no need to reset the database